# Prove a continous function is subharmonic on unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, riemann-surfaces

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $v$ be continuous on $|z|<1$ and subharmonic on $0<|z|<1$. Show that $v$ is subharmonic on all of $|z|<1.$
>
> Here, we say $\varphi$ is subharmonic on $U$ if any closed disc $D(z,r) \subset U$ of center $z$ and radius $r$ one has
>   $$\varphi(z) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \varphi(z+ re^{i\theta}) \, d\theta.$$

### ----------------------------

My attempt:

It is enough to show that for some $r$, we have 
$$v(0) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} v(re^{it}) \, dt.$$
There is a hint: consider the $$v_{\epsilon}(z)=v(z)+\epsilon \log |z|$$
I have no idea how to use this hint since $v_{\epsilon}(z)$ behaves even worse near $0$. It will go to infinity when $z\to 0$. So what does this hint mean?

Any hints and answers are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $v_\epsilon(0)=-\infty$, not $\infty$. And that's *better*, not worse: It's obvious that $v_\epsilon$ is subharmonic since it's subharmonic in $0<|z|<1$ and equals $-\infty$ at $0$.

The tricky part is that $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}v_\epsilon(0)\ne v(0).$$

Major thing about subhamonic functions: The inequality in the definition is required to hold only for $0<r<\delta(z)$ (this is important, for example this is why $v_\epsilon$ is obviously subharmonic: for $z\ne0$ take $\delta(z)=|z|$), but if $u$ *is* subharmonic then the inequality holds for all $r$.

So assume $0<r<1/2$ and $0<|z|<r$. Then $$v_\epsilon(z)\le\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}v_\epsilon(z+re^{it})\,dt.$$
Let $\epsilon\to0$ in *that* inequality, and then let $z\to0$.

Comment: Why don't we consider the $v(x)+\log|z|$. It is subharmonic as you said. And $\log |z|$ is subharmonic. So by the closedness of the set of subharmonic functions under linear combination, we can have $v$ is subharmonic.

Comment: @LeoGardon Oh dear. Who told you a linear combination of subharmonic functions is subharmonic? There's a little detail you're leaving out there...

Comment: A stupid mistake... It only holds for positive coefficients...